# Minimum working example for using decorators with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I would like to use decorators as described on the [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) site and it seems my `package.json` should look something like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.0"
  }
}
```

According to the [Usage / Via Node API](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators#via-node-api) section, to be able to use it I should first `require` a `.transform("code", ...);`.

The code itself comes from their [Simple class decorator example](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators#simple-class-decorator).

My complete `annotation.js` then looks like this

```
require("@babel/core").transform("code", {
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"]
});

@annotation
class MyClass { }

function annotation(target) {
   target.annotated = true;
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass.annotated);
```

Unfortunately, when running `node annotation.js` from the command line I get

```
C:\path_to\annotation.js:5
@annotation
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I seem to be missing something significant, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: did you solve this? Same issue here.